# how to capture specific coordinate on webcam using javascript?

Tags: javascript

i know how to capture video , this is my code

```
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
snap.addEventListener("click", function() {
    context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 1000, 500);

});
```

but how to capture specific coordinates ?

change drawImage() function parametere just resize the picture but still capture whole picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't avoid *capturing* the entire camera frame, because that's just how the camera API works. But you can use the [overload of `drawImage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) that takes a source rectangle as an argument:

```
context.drawImage(video, sx, sy, sWidth, sHeight, 0, 0, 1000, 500);
```

Here, `sx, sy, sWidth, sHeight` indicates the rectangle inside the video frame that you want to draw. This is then stretched to fit inside the destination rectangle; if you don't want any stretching, make sure the width and height are the same.